# Angular project created but it haven't environment.prod.ts and environment.ts

Tags: angular-cli

Angular CLI: 15.0.0/Package Manager: npm 9.1.1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQAmW.png)

i didnt understand why it haven't the environment folder(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMW9.png)

Comment: The latest version of the CLI does not include the environment folder or files. You have to add them by hand. https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 15 CLI does not create environments folder when creating an angular project via ng new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558182/angular-15-cli-does-not-create-environments-folder-when-creating-an-angular-proj)