# Angular 15 CLI does not create environments folder when creating an angular project via ng new

Tags: angular-cli

Similar to an Angular 14 generated project I want to have separate development and production environments but when creating a project using `ng new`:

```
ng new my-app
```

this does not create the environments folder or set this up.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add what versions of `npm` and `NodeJS` are you using?

Comment: npm v- 8.19.2 , NodeJS v- v18.12.1

Answer (score 120, accepted):

See [Angular - Configure Environment Specific Defaults](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults)

EDIT:- As predicted, [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24381)

> After the release of Angular CLI 15.1, a generation schematic will be available to add environment files for all existing build configurations within a project.
> Example usage:
>
> `ng g environments`

---

To manually create:

If you want to recreate environments, follow these steps:

- Create `environments` directory
- Create your custom environments

  - `environment.ts`
  - `environment.prod.ts`
  - `environment.staging.ts` etc.
- Update your `angular.json` or `project.json` to do `fileReplacements` where the paths are from project root to the environment file for `replace` and `with`:

```
  "configurations": {
       "production": {
          ...
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/some-app/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/some-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
        },
        "development": {
          ...
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
```

Comment: I initially deleted as I'm not yet sure it this'll actually work i.e. if `fileReplacements` will still work. Undeleted and I'll let someone tell me since this answer referenced in a comment

Comment: I confirmed this to work. You just need to edit and remove the "apps/some-app" part (the pending edits queue is full). Then I put `export default "hello dev"` and `export default "hello prod"` in the environments and `import environment from "./environments/environment"; console.error(environment)` in main.ts. `ng build` shows the prod print outputted and `ng build -c development` shows the development print

Comment: Thanks,, for reference `apps/some-app` coming from nx workspace. But can be any path project root to environment files

Comment: I dont't understand why they removed the environment folder... It's a step backward to create the folder "manually". I used this very often for local development and production builds (server address as example)

Comment: ng g environments is not worked for me

Comment: @NimashaMadhushani I suggest opening a new question if you're still facing issues. Include your angular version (>15.1) and `angular.json` file

Comment: I created directories manually. @AndrewAllen Still I am finding another issue. If you don't mind may I share the link to that question

Comment: Also facing the same issue

Answer (score 19):

I haven't tested this all out yet but there seems to be a new command:

```
ng generate environments
```

Here is a Youtube video describing the steps needing to be done.
There seems to be quite a bit of steps to configure afterward.  But I plan on giving it a try.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IXwN4XJywQ

Comment: should be ```ng generate environments```

Answer (score 5):

### An Alternative

Because it looks like the normative environments setup is currently nonexistent and|or may becoming nonstandard, I thought I'd share an alternative pattern that I use for any non-Angular projects (including backend/Node) and now on Angular v15.0.0 that works very well.

It leverages the standard `.env` (and `.env.{type}`) files with just a little setup and looks something like this...

```
{app-name}
  |-environment
    |-env.ts
    |-path.ts
    |-index.ts
  |-.env
  |-.env.mock
  |-.env.dev
  |-.env.staging
  |-tsconfig.json
  |-package.json
```

#### `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "SET TYPE=mock& start-command",  # "SET ..." for Windows setup.
    "SET TYPE=dev& start-command",
    "SET TYPE=qa& start-command"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "n.n.n"
  }
}
```

#### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@env": [ "environment/index.ts" ]
        },
    },
}
```

#### `environment/index.ts`

```
export { env } from './env';
```

#### `environment/path.ts`

```
module.exports = {
    '': '.env',
    'undefined': '.env',
    'prod': '.env',
    'mock': '.env.mock',
    'dev': '.env.dev',
    'qa': '.env.staging',
}[ process.env.TYPE ];  // npm script "SET TYPE={type}& start-command"
```

#### `environment/env.ts`

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('./path') });

export const env = new (class Environment {
    TYPE: string = '';
    NODE_ENV: string = '';
    PORT: number = -1;
    
    constructor(env: Environment = <Environment>{}) {
        const { TYPE, NODE_ENV, PORT } = { ...this, ...env };
        
        this.TYPE = TYPE;
        this.NODE_ENV = NODE_ENV;
        this.PORT = PORT*1;
        
        return this;
    }
    
})({ ...process.env });
```

#### `src/example.ts`

```
import { env } from '@env';

const { TYPE, NODE_ENV, PORT } = env;
let http = HTTP;

if (TYPE === 'mock') http = mockHTTP;

export { http };
```

### Disclaimer

> "*Angular is built with Angular CLI, which is a node application, but you aren't able to access process.env directly from within the app during that build process, as it's not processed as a Node application.*"
> -- [Use process.env in Angular 5 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496438/use-process-env-in-angular-5-environment)

It would be very nice to find an elegant workaround for this.

Comment: I have a shell script that does token replacement in my "env" file on deployment. on local i just have a local.env file that is git ignored. `find ./dist/ -type f -exec sed -i "s|#{SERVER}#|$server|g" {} +`

Answer (score 5):

After the Angular 15 version the environments folder are not created by default. You have to manually create them.
Use this best provision provided by Angular to create new enviornments swiftly. The benifit is that it'll update the angular json file as well for the created environment.ts file

```
ng generate environments
```

They will have this boiler plate in them:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

I never recommend to create them manually but still to manually create environments, follow these steps:

Create environments directory and then create your custom environments like the below

- environment.ts
- environment.prod.ts
- environment.staging.ts

Then you have to upadte the angular.json file to replace the enviorments at build time.

```
   "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          },
        ]
      },
      "dev": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
          },
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, in new Angular versions, the environments folder is not created by default when generating a new project using the ng new command. However, you can easily set up separate development and production environments yourself by following these steps:

1. Create the Environments folder manually in the root directory of your Angular project by typing the following command:

   ```
   mkdir src/environments
   ```
2. Inside the environments folder, create two TypeScript files:
   environment.prod.ts and environment.ts by typing the following command:

   ```
   touch src/environments/environment.prod.ts
   touch src/environments/environment.ts
   ```
3. Open the environment.prod.ts file and define the production environment variables specific to your project. Consider the following as an example:

   ```
   export const environment = {
     production: true,
     apiUrl: 'https://portfolio.com/api',
     // Other production environment variables if you have
   };
   ```
4. Open the environment.ts file and define the development environment variables as follows:

   ```
   export const environment = {
     production: false,
     apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/api',
     // Other production environment variables if you have
    };
   ```
5. Now, you can use the environment variables in your Angular code. As an example, you can import the environment file in a component and access the variables like the following:

   ```
   import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
   // Usage example
   if (!environment.production) {
     console.log('Development Mode');
   };
   ```
6. With the above-mentioned steps, you have set up separate development and production environments in your Angular project. Now you can modify the environment variables in the respective files based on your project's requirements.

- Note: Remember to update the values of apiUrl or other variables to match your actual API endpoints or any other environment-specific configurations.

Answer (score 2):

[The `environments` folder is no longer necessary in Angular 15.](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8)

If your workflow still needs that folder, you can downgrade with `npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.10`, then create a new project with `ng new`.

Comment: Do you know what we should use instead? What I can see they aren't adressing it in their blogpost.

Comment: See Andrew Allen's answer if you still need this feature. According to my research it's the way people are suggesting to replace it with. I personally don't use this "environments" feature and I think they removed it because only experts or non-Angile teams are using it. Anyway, even the "enableProdMode" control has been moved somewhere else by Angular

Comment: Wait..... I use the environment files to store my environment-specific app configuration. They made quite a bold decision to axe it just because we don't need one property on an entire class.????

Comment: @samneric It is still available, just not create when create app: `ng generate environments` https://angular.io/cli/generate#environments

Answer (score 0):

Angular v14 no longer create environments folder by default, if you need it just run `ng g environments`