# Angular: Cannot find environment file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I followed several tutorials and they all say at some point "now go to `src/environments`".  But that folder just does not exist in my project!
I tried to delete the whole project and recreate it, but it doesn't help.

This is how I do it. Open cmd and then:

```
1. cd my_path
2. npm install -g @angular/cli
3. ng new webversion
   --> Angular routing? Yes
   --> Stylesheet: CSS
4. cd webversion
5. npm install bootstrap
6. npm install firebase @angular/fire
```

Now the tutorials start using `src/environments`. But I just do not have that folder.
This is my `angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "webversion": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/webversion",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "webversion:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "webversion:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "webversion:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the tutorials tt should contain a "reference" to the environment folder, and a file replacement info about which files are going to be replaced in production mode. But it doesn't have either of that...

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 15 CLI does not create environments folder when creating an angular project via ng new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558182/angular-15-cli-does-not-create-environments-folder-when-creating-an-angular-proj)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update** -

See Angular docs directly [Configure Environment Specific Defaults](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults)

or [Angular 15 CLI does not create environments folder when creating an angular project via ng new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558182/angular-15-cli-does-not-create-environments-folder-when-creating-an-angular-proj)

---

*This is the outdated answer, though you can still manually create.*

You'll have to create your environment files manually.

See [Configure Environment Specific Defaults](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults)

This was removed from Angular 15 CLI in order to simplify the minimal app created via `ng new` in the new standalone world. The  reason they did this is that it should be really simple to create and bootstrap a single component with minimal additional files. It does mean older tutorials may be out of date.

- Create environments directory
- Create your custom environments

  - environment.ts
  - environment.prod.ts
  - environment.staging.ts etc.

`angular.json` - see `<----`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "webversion": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/webversion",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [ // <------------------------------------
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "webversion:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "webversion:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "webversion:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need additional configurations, duplicate the production one and rename.